# PHP generating new session id

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a web server with the following PHP configuration. I found that my server is generating new SESSION ID within an hour. Now sure what's wrong.

```
 session.name                     = PHPSESSID
 session.auto_start               = Off
 session.use_trans_sid            = 0
 session.cookie_domain            = .domain.name
 session.cookie_path             = /
 session.use_strict_mode          = 1
 session.use_cookies              = 1
 session.use_only_cookies         = 1
 session.cookie_lifetime          = 365*24*60*60
 session.cookie_secure            = 1
 session.cookie_httponly          = 1
 session.cookie_samesite          = Strict
 session.cache_expire             = 180
 session.gc_maxlifetime           = 14400
 session.gc_probability           = 1
 session.gc_divisor               = 1000
 session.sid_length               = 240
 session.sid_bits_per_character   = 6

edit: I'm following [OWASP cheatsheet][1] of php.


  [1]: https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/PHP_Configuration_Cheat_Sheet.md
```

Comment: Might be useful to tell us what you want it to do

Comment: Creating a service where a user can some ask specific question. I want it to remain logged in for a day or so.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with session.cookie_lifetime=365*24*60*60. Putting multiplied number solved it.